# Question on interpretation of covariates in repeated measures analysis

Tags: repeated-measures, manova

I am currently having difficulties with the statistical analysis of my research. My research is the effect of a drug on 3 measures, upper limb impairment and 2 qualtiy of life measures at two time points, baseline to 2 weeks and 12 weeks. This is done in only one group of participants.

One-way, repeated measures MANOVA analysis revealed there was a change in all three measures across all-time points.

Currently, I am trying to investigate if there are any effect of time-invariant covariates on the output of MANOVA. I have three covariates, disease severity, disease sub-type and employment status. My problem is interpreting the output of the analysis. Do I assess the multivariate, within subjects output (i.e. interaction with time) OR the tests of between subjects?

I will be glad if anyone could offer some answers.

Comment: Whether there are covariates on the output depends on your code, not on the output. You interpret all of the output.